# How to convert google.protobuf.Struct field in java.util.Map<String, Object>?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grpc, proto

I have a message defined quotation_item.proto file which has google.protobuf.Struct field to parse metadata JSON.

```
message QuotationItemEntry {
    // Other fields
    google.protobuf.Struct metadata = 15;
}
```

Also metadata field is defined in Java entity class

```
public class QuotationItem {
    // Other entity fields
    private Map<String, Object> metadata;
}
```

I want to store the QuotationItemEntry object passed in gRPC request using spring boot application but not able to convert `google.protobuf.Struct` field in `java.util.Map<String, Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `google.protobuf.Struct`'s field values are not supported in their native representations. Instead, they are wrapped by `com.google.protobuf.Value`. So with `google.protobuf.Struct#getFieldsMap()` method, the result is a `Map<String, Value>`. You would need to populate entry values manually.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [voidzcy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11500161/voidzcy) has correctly pointed out the intricacies of dealing with Google Protobuf's Struct in Java, specifically the use of Value to wrap the fields. I'd like to offer some deeper understanding for those new to Protobuf in overall, to illuminate why this design choice was made and how it impacts you as a developer.

Protobuf's Struct type is designed to be a flexible container that can accommodate a variety of data types. This design choice is particularly beneficial for handling semi-structured or dynamic data. The flexibility allows the Struct to capture data that does not conform to a fixed schema. While this is incredibly useful for handling a variety of data shapes, it comes with a trade-off: you lose strong type guarantees.

To understand a little bit deeper what defines the `Struct` well-known message in the core library of `Protobuf` we can look at the `.proto` descriptions found on [Github](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto)

The code below is taken from the opensource repository of google protobuf:

```
message Struct {
  // Unordered map of dynamically typed values.
  map<string, Value> fields = 1;
}
```

So from the above code snippet, we can tell that a struct is essentially using `map<>` we discussed above, and storing `Value` to mapped strings.

The `Value` is another message that defined on the same `.proto` file here is how `Value` look like:

```
message Value {
  oneof kind {
    NullValue null_value = 1;
    double number_value = 2;
    string string_value = 3;
    bool bool_value = 4;
    Struct struct_value = 5;
    ListValue list_value = 6;
  }
}
```

We can look also the last entities in the `struct.proto` file to know that value can be served as "Null" or a "List" of `Value`:

```
enum NullValue {
  NULL_VALUE = 0;
}

message ListValue {
  repeated Value values = 1;
}
```

Some languages and frameworks may use the internal protobuf structure without giving the developer and "JSON Like" interface to interact with thier `Struct`'s

For example, if we have the following JSON data:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "domain": "bar",
    "isAuthenticated": true
}
```

we will have the internal `Protobuf` pseudo-code structure like:

```py
Struct {
    fields {
        key: "name"
        value {
            string_value: "foo"
        }
    }
    fields {
        key: "isAuthenticated"
        value {
            bool_value: true
        }
    }
    fields {
        key: "id"
        value {
            number_value: 1
        }
    }
    fields {
        key: "domain"
        value {
            string_value: "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to read more about it I have posted a [Blog regarding this topic](https://blog.sylk.build/blog/protobuf-map-vs-struct)

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! Also the blog post is great!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can stream over metadata keys and collect them as a map. This could solve your problem.

```
    public Map<String, String> getMetadataMap(Metadata metadata) {
            Map<String, String> metadataMap = metadata.keys().stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    key -> key,
                    key -> metadata.get(Metadata.Key.of(key,
                                        Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER))));
            return metadataMap;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for kotlin:

```
fun Struct.toMap(): Map<String, Any?> =
    this.fieldsMap.mapValues { it.value.toAny() }

fun Value.toAny(): Any? =
    when (kindCase) {
        NULL_VALUE -> null
        NUMBER_VALUE -> numberValue
        STRING_VALUE -> stringValue
        BOOL_VALUE -> boolValue
        STRUCT_VALUE -> structValue.toMap()
        LIST_VALUE -> listValue.valuesList.map { it.toAny() }
        else -> error("Incorrect protobuf value $this")
    }
```

Usage:

```
val map: Map<String, Any?> = youProtoStruct.toMap()
```